# Compare 2 dataframes

Tags: r

So I have 2 data frames, a and b:

```
start <- c(sort(sample(0:10000, 5)), sort(sample(0:10000, 5)))
stop <- start + sample(100:200, 10)
numbers <- 1:10
names <- purrr::map_chr(numbers,~paste0("X",.x))

a <- data.frame(chr=rep(c(1:2), each=3), pos=c(sort(sample(0:10000, 3)), sort(sample(0:10000, 3))))
b <- data.frame(chr=rep(c(1:2), each=5), start=start, stop=stop, name=names)
```

I would like to populate columns in a with information extracted from b.

1. First extra column in a: *"is each a$pos within the start/stop in b?"*. And if so, report b$name - matching by chr between the two dataframes.
   So that would be something like
   `ifelse(between(a$pos, b$start, b$stop), b$name, "Not_within_range")` (ok this code doesn't match by chr column beforehand but you get the idea).
2. Second extra column in a: report the b$name corresponding to the row has the closest distance between a$pos and either b$start or b$stop (matching by chr again).

I've gotten some sort of results using rowwise functions (ie `apply(a, 2, fun(x))`) but it's pretty ugly. I'd be keen to see suggestions (tidyverse suggestions very welcome!).

Answer (score 1):

your sample data is not reprodicuble (missing set.seed() ), so I used the sample data below...

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(a);setDT(b)
# perform update non-equi join to get the name
a[b, name := i.name, on = .(chr, pos >= start, pos <= stop)][]
#    chr  pos name
# 1:   1 1613 <NA>
# 2:   1 2979 <NA>
# 3:   1 9981 <NA>
# 4:   2  554 <NA>
# 5:   2 4468 <NA>
# 6:   2 9358   X9

# perform rolling join to get nearest in two steps
# 1. melt b to long format
b.melt <- melt(b, id.vars = c("chr", "name"), measure.vars = c("start", "stop"))
# 2. perform rolling join to nearest start/stop value
a[, name.nearest := b.melt[a, name, on = .(chr, value = pos), roll = "nearest"]]

#    chr  pos name name.nearest
# 1:   1 1613 <NA>           X1
# 2:   1 2979 <NA>           X4
# 3:   1 9981 <NA>           X5
# 4:   2  554 <NA>           X6
# 5:   2 4468 <NA>           X7
# 6:   2 9358   X9           X9
```

**sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
start <- c(sort(sample(0:10000, 5)), sort(sample(0:10000, 5)))
stop <- start + sample(100:200, 10)
numbers <- 1:10
names <- purrr::map_chr(numbers,~paste0("X",.x))

a <- data.frame(chr=rep(c(1:2), each=3), pos=c(sort(sample(0:10000, 3)), sort(sample(0:10000, 3))))
b <- data.frame(chr=rep(c(1:2), each=5), start=start, stop=stop, name=names)

#   chr  pos
# 1   1 1613
# 2   1 2979
# 3   1 9981
# 4   2  554
# 5   2 4468
# 6   2 9358

#    chr start stop name
# 1    1  1841 2009   X1
# 2    1  2462 2652   X2
# 3    1  2510 2666   X3
# 4    1  2985 3176   X4
# 5    1  8717 8825   X5
# 6    2  3370 3562   X6
# 7    2  4760 4931   X7
# 8    2  6745 6870   X8
# 9    2  9333 9439   X9
# 10   2  9818 9959  X10
```